# How to get specific month on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date

How can I get the specific date month coming from the backend on angularJS

I wish to add something like this:

```
 var curMonth = new Date().getMonth();
      var monthData = vm.paymentsData[0].date.Date().getMonth();
      if (curMonth == monthData) {
           console.log ("Same Month");
      }
```

Im getting error on:

```
var monthData = vm.paymentsData[0].date.Date().getMonth();
```

it says:

```
angular.js:14328 TypeError: vm.paymentsData[0].date.Date is not a function
```

Thanks

[Data from the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV7qo.png)

Comment: _"I wish to add something like this:"_  So what's your question??

Comment: how to get the month if not new Date. Im getting error on angular.js:14328 TypeError: vm.paymentsData[0].date.Date is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be written as follows:

```
var curMonth = new Date().getMonth();
// this maybe a string .. and you cannot call Date() function in that way.
var monthData = vm.paymentsData[0].date;
// Date function should be called this way.
var monData = (new Date(monthData)).getMonth();
if (curMonth == monData) {
    console.log ("Same Month");
}
```